# Value not getting passed from child to parent component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As you can see in the two components below, i want to delete the recipes(in app component) from a button click in the panelcomponent,
i have a method in app to delete the recipe, and a prop(onclick) send to child panelcomponent. Panel then gets the index from the map of recipes, and after the button click it executes the handleDelet method to  send the index back to parent. but No this is not working !

```
    class App extends React.Component {

  state={
    addRecipe:{recipeName:"",ingredients:[]},
    recipes:[{recipeName:"Apple",ingredients:["apple","onion","spice"]},
            {recipeName:"Apple",ingredients:["apple","onion","spice"]},
            {recipeName:"Apple",ingredients:["apple","onion","spice"]}]
  }
handleDelete = (index) => {
  let recipes = this.state.recipes.slice();
  recipes.splice(index,1); //deleting the index value from recipe
  this.setState({recipes}) //setting the state to new value
  console.log(index,recipes)
}
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <PanelComponent recipes={this.state.recipes} onClick={()=>this.handleDelete(index)}/>
        <ModalComponent />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class PanelComponent extends React.Component {
  handleDelete = (index) => {
    this.props.onClick(index); //sending index to parent after click
    console.log(index)
  }
  render() {

    return (
      <PanelGroup accordion>
        {this.props.recipes.map( (recipe,index) => {
          return(

          <Panel eventKey={index} key={index}>
          <Panel.Heading>
            <Panel.Title toggle>{recipe.recipeName}</Panel.Title>
          </Panel.Heading>
          <Panel.Body collapsible>
            <ListGroup>
              {recipe.ingredients.map((ingredient)=>{
                return(<ListGroupItem>{ingredient}</ListGroupItem>);
              })} 
            </ListGroup>
            <Button bsStyle="danger" onClick={()=>this.handleDelete(index)}>Delete</Button>
              <EditModalComponent />
          </Panel.Body>
        </Panel>

          );

        })}


      </PanelGroup>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: ithink you are sending the function wrongly as props, try this instead <PanelComponent recipes={this.state.recipes} onClick={this.handleDelete}/>  else you are sneding the result of the function as props rather than the function itself

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier could you edit and show me please. thank you

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier i am getting the index value now after clicking not updating tho

Comment: is the index value in the parent or the child?

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier it works now thank you

Comment: then please mark the answer as correct

Answer (score 2):

Thea actual error in your code is that while using arrow function in the onClick in parent, you are passing the wrong parameter, instead of `{()=>this.handleDelete(index)}` what you should write is
`{(value)=>this.handleDelete(value)}`, However, that also not necessary and you could simple write `{this.handleDelete}` in App since your handleDelete function is already binded and it received the values from the Child component.

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <PanelComponent recipes={this.state.recipes} onClick={(value)=>this.handleDelete(value)}/>
        <ModalComponent />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

The difference in writing `{()=>this.handleDelete(index)}` vs `{(value)=>this.handleDelete(value)}` is that in the first case, you are explicitly passing the index that you get from the map function in your App component while in the second case, the value passed from the child component when you execute `this.props.onClick(value)` is being provided to the `handleDelete` function.

Answer (score 1):

you are sending the function wrongly as props. you are sending the result of the function as props rather than the function itself

```
  class App extends React.Component {

 state={
addRecipe:{recipeName:"",ingredients:[]},
recipes:[{recipeName:"Apple",ingredients:["apple","onion","spice"]},
        {recipeName:"Apple",ingredients:["apple","onion","spice"]},
        {recipeName:"Apple",ingredients:["apple","onion","spice"]}]
 }
handleDelete = (index) => {
 let recipes = this.state.recipes.slice();
 recipes.splice(index,1); //deleting the index value from recipe
 this.setState({recipes}) //setting the state to new value
 console.log(index,recipes)
 }
 render() {
   return (
     <div className="container">
         //change here
       <PanelComponent recipes={this.state.recipes} onClick={this.handleDelete}/>
    <ModalComponent />
  </div>
  );
 }
 }
```

Comment: The OP is not sending the result of the function, its an arrow function syntax

Comment: fine but he is not sending the reference of the function either

Comment: no That not the error, the thing is `{()=>this.handleDelete(index)}` in this call the handleDelete function gets the index from the map function above, while writing `{(value)=>this.handleDelete(value)}` it gets the value passed when it is executed and passed that on to the handleDelete function

Comment: Yes what you suggest works fine, but the explanation of your answer is incorrect, its important to know why your way works and not what other person uses